# JavaScript : return maximum possible `HH:MM`

Tags: javascript

#### **Leetcode problem**:

You are given a string that represents time in the format hh:mm. Some of the digits are blank (represented by ?). Fill in `?` such that the time represented by this string is the maximum possible. Maximum time: 23:59, minimum time: 00:00. You can assume that input string is always valid.

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: How this isn't a question if it got your attention @RoryMcCrossan ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
maxTime = (time) => {
        const timeArr = time.split(":");
        let hr = timeArr[0];
        let mn = String(timeArr[1]);
        if (mn.includes("?")) {
          const mnArr = mn.split("");
          if (mnArr[0] === "?" && mnArr[1] === "?") {
            mn = "59";
          } else if (mnArr[0] === "?") {
            mn = "5" + mnArr[1];
          } else if (mnArr[1] === "?") {
            const temp = mnArr[0] === "5" ? "9" : "0";
            mn = mnArr[0] + temp;
          }
        }
        if (hr.includes("?")) {
          const hrArr = hr.split("");
          if (hrArr[0] === "?" && hrArr[1] === "?") {
            hr = "23";
          } else if (hrArr[0] === "?") {
            hr = "2" + hrArr[1];
            hr = Number(hr) <= 24 ? "1" + hrArr[1] : hr;
          } else if (hrArr[1] === "?") {
            const temp = hrArr[0] === "2" ? "3" : "9";
            hr = hrArr[0] + temp;
          }
        }

        return `(${time}) => ${hr}:${mn}`;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the replace function ability of [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement).  The second parameter passed in is the position of the ?, so use that to look up the max value for that position in an array.

```js
const maxValues = ["2", "3", ":", "5", "9"];
const maxTime = (time) => time.replace(/\?/g, (s, p, str) => {
  if (p === 1 && str[0] !== '2' && str[0] !== '?' ) {
    return '9';
  }
  return maxValues[p];
});

console.log(maxTime("?1:1?"))
console.log(maxTime("??:??"))
console.log(maxTime("11:11"))
console.log(maxTime("1?:?1"))
```

Comment: Breaks on time values less than 10:00.  Example, 09:00 is a valid time, but 0?:00 would return "03:00" - I like the approach tho

Comment: Special case when it's the second digit and the first digit isn't a 2.  It's less appealing now :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very elegant solution but it addresses the problem I pointed out in my reply to James, where the send H in HH can be either 9 or 3 depending on the time.  This also is just different but also valid.

```js
maxTime = (strTime) => {
  let [...str] = strTime;
    if (str[0] == "?") { str[0] = "2"; }
    if (str[1] == "?" && str[0] < "2") { str[1] = "9"; } else { str[1] = "3"; }
    if (str[3] == "?") { str[3] = "5"; }
    if (str[4] == "?") { str[4] = "9"; }
    return str.join('');
}

console.log(maxTime("?2:22")); // 22:22
console.log(maxTime("2?:22")); // 23:22
console.log(maxTime("22:?2")); // 22:52
console.log(maxTime("22:2?")); // 22:29
console.log(maxTime("0?:??")); // 09:59
console.log(maxTime("1?:??")); // 19:59
console.log(maxTime("??:??")); // 23:59
```

or a loop

```js
const max = "29:59";
maxTime = (strTime) => {
  let [...str] = strTime;
  for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) { if (strTime[x] == "?") { str[x] = max[x]; }}
  if (str[0] == "2" && strTime[1] == "?") { str[1] = "3"; }
  return str.join('');
}

console.log(maxTime("?2:22")); // 22:22
console.log(maxTime("2?:22")); // 23:22
console.log(maxTime("22:?2")); // 22:52
console.log(maxTime("22:2?")); // 22:29
console.log(maxTime("0?:??")); // 09:59
console.log(maxTime("1?:??")); // 19:59
console.log(maxTime("??:??")); // 23:59
```